# MySQL group by query for similar values

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table:

```
  -------------
  COL1 | COL2 | 
  -------------
  3   |  A    |
  5   |  B    |
  7   |  C    |
  5   |  A    |
  7   |  B    |
  10  |  C    |
  -------------
```

Desired table output:

```
  --------------
  COL1 | COL2  | 
  --------------
   3   |  A    |
   5   |       |
   7   |  B    |
   5   |       |
   7   |  C    |
   10  |       |
  --------------
```

Basically as 'Group by Col2' where Col 1 values will be with respect to Col2 value.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a bit more? I am quite confused by your question...

Comment: Can you better explain the logic for the transformation?

Comment: this transformation have no meaning only if he want every second row will be other letter

Comment: I have removed your ALL CAPS. Now it's up to you to explain "where Col 1 values will be with respect to Col2 value" before your question gets closed as "unclear what you're asking". Please edit your question.

Comment: Issues of data display should be handled in the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the list of `col1` values associated with each `col2`.  The easiest way to get this is on a single *row*:

```
select col2, group_concat(col1)
from table t
group by col2;
```

On the other hand, you might not want *aggregation*.  You might simply want to sort the results:

```
select col1, col2
from table t
order by col2, col1;
```

This is slightly different from your desired results, because the `col2` values appears on each row.  Fixing that in SQL takes a bit more logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon !!! group_concat() function provides me the desired results..